# How to "tell" a parent context which managed objects it has to delete and/or insert?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a parent `NSmanagedObjectContext` in the main queue, and a child `NSManagedObjectContext` in a private queue. I pass a set of managed objects in the parent context to its child. Then, the child context have the managed objects from its parent, and then it is inserted new managed objects. I make some processing in the private queue with all the managed objects in the child context, the ones that came from the parent and its own new ones, and at the end of the process, I need to tell the parent:

- Which of its managed objects need to be deleted
- Which of its managed objects need to be replaced with the new managed objects in the child
- Which of the managed objects in the child need to be inserted into the parent

Is it possible to do that with a parent/child relationship between contexts? Even if they belong to different queues? Or is a parent/child relationship only suitable to perform changes in the attributes of certain managed objects, but it is not for deletions and insertions of managed objects?

If it is not possible to manage this scenario with a parent/child relationship, what the approach should be?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** The examples I find just use a child context to edit a managed object of the parent and then apply the changes to the parent when edition ends. So I'm not sure if it is possible to use a child context to also delete or insert objects in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet (with some chunks missing) that does a child based delete and then passes it up to the parent.

```
[childContext performBlock:^{
    // query array of messages

    // LOTS OF CODE

    // Loop through them and delete each message


    // Loop through each message
    for (id emptyMessage in emptyMessages) {

        i++;
        // Work in ContextBlocks...
        //            [childContext performBlock:^{

        __block AHRSMessage *msg = (AHRSMessage *) [childContext objectWithID:emptyMessage];

        [childContext deleteObject:msg];


        if (i % modFactor == 0) {
            self.percentDone = i / totalRecords;

            NSLog(@"%.1f Saving ...", self.percentDone * 100);


            NSError *error;
            if (![childContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"\n error => %@ \n", [error localizedDescription]);
                NSLog(@" error => %@ ", [error userInfo]);
                [NSException raise:@"Database Write Error" format:@"%@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]];

                //                    abort();
            }

            [parentContext performBlock:^{
                NSError *errrror;
                if (![parentContext save:&errrror]) {
                    NSLog(@"\n error => %@ \n", [error localizedDescription]);
                    NSLog(@" error => %@ ", [error userInfo]);
                    [NSException raise:@"Database Write Error" format:@"%@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]];

                    //                        abort();
                }
            }];
        }

        //            }];

    }
```

The child save writes it to memory and to actually write to disk you have to call the parent save.  As you see i do one after another - but this is not required.

Comment: Thanks. So... no need to set a merge policy nor doing anything else? Just saving the child updates the parent with its changes?

Comment: I cannot say for sure -  I have not run into a case where i've needed one yet.

Answer (score 1):

When the child context calls `save()`, the changes are pushed up to the parent context. That means, the entire object graph of the parent context is updated to reflect the state of the child context.

Thus you do not have to do anything. The deleted objects will be gone, the added objects will be there, and the edited objects will be updated.

Comment: Thanks. So, there is no need to set a merge policy? I really found few examples of using such setting...

Comment: Right - no need to set a merge policy in most cases. From your description I presume that the main context won't change the same objects while the child context is doing its work. Therefore, no merging necessary.

Comment: In effect it seems to work that way, thanks so much!